# rspec Unable to find button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

**spec/controllers/undertakes_controller_spec.rb** :

```
describe 'undertake comment' do
 let(:user) do
  build(:user)
 end
 before do
  user1=create(:user)
  user1.id=1
  login_as(user1)
  @undertake=create(:undertake)
 end
 it 'can create comment' do
  visit undertake_path(@undertake)
  expect(current_path).to eq undertake_path(@undertake)
  within("form#undertake-form-test") do
   fill_in "content" , with: "heyheyhey"
  end
  click_button "Send"
  expect(page).to have_content 'heyheyhey'
 end
end
```

**undertakes/show.html.erb** :

```
<%= form_for(@comment , url: undertake_comments_url(@undertake)  , id: 'undertake-form-test') do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content , class:"form-label"  %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content,  placeholder: '返信する' , class:'text-area-css' %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Send" , class:' btn btn-primary btn-lg'  %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Why do I have error `Capybara::ElementNotFound:Unable to find button "Send"`.

Please help me.

Comment: Try adding an id and use that. eg) `<%= f.submit "Send" , class:' btn btn-primary btn-lg' id:'send-btn'  %>` and `click_button 'send-btn'`

Comment: Sorry,I tried that. but I still have error. Do you know how to solve it other way?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this doesnt look like a controller spec to me. Looks like you are blending it with a feature spec. A controller spec should look like https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be testing a controller like so

```
RSpec.describe UndertakesController, :type => :controller do  
  describe 'POST #create' do
    before do
      user1 = create(:user)
      user1.id = 1
      login_as(user1)
      @undertake = build(:undertake)
    end
    post :create, :params => { :undertake => { @undertake } }
    expect(Undertake.count).to eq(1)
  end
end
```

just an example of how you would do the creation.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! So should I write code not in controllers but in features in this case?

Comment: The code you pasted would be better suited for a feature spec yes.